# Cases where used-defined conversions are disallowed in conversion sequence

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, c++17, implicit-conversion

Looking at this: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Viable_functions)

I found that I can hardly precisely understand this paragraph:

> User-defined conversions (both converting constructors and user-defined conversion functions) are prohibited from taking part in implicit conversion sequence where it would make it possible to apply more than one user-defined conversion. Specifically, they are prohibited if the target of the conversion is the first parameter of a constructor or the implicit object parameter of a user-defined conversion function, and that constructor/user-defined conversion is a candidate for
>
> - copy-initialization of a class by user-defined conversion,
> - initialization by a conversion function,
> - initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding,
> - initialization by constructor where the argument is a temporary in class copy-initialization,
> - initialization by list-initialization where the initializer list has exactly one element that is itself an initializer list, and the target is the first parameter of a constructor of class X, and the conversion is to X or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) X

I guess I understand the idea, but the cases seem weird to me.

There is an example below given for the last case, so that seems clear.

But isn't the 1-st bullet just a particular case of the 4-th one?

Any similarly why mention both the 2-nd and the 3-rd when the latter seems (rather obviously, if I'm not crazy) to be a particular case of the former?

Is it just for emphasizing certain cases, or am I misunderstanding something?

Also the 1-st one seems to overlap with the following 3...

Why isn't it just 'a candidate for initialization by user defined conversion'? To me it seems that would cover all the cases (maybe not necessarily that, but definitely something simpler than what's written).

P.S.: sorry for the broadness of the question, I'm just completely confused looking at this :)

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but cppreference is a community effort, which can have inconsistencies and redundancies (even the standard has those). The standard discusses this in [\[over.best.ics\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#4) and only has 3 different cases.

Comment: @GoranFlegar I understand it's a community effort, and thus I'm trying to find those inconsistencies (or understand things I don't); I've already found I few ones that were fixed so I guess it's a good effort from my side as well :) as for the link, as I see, cppreference tries to mirror what's there, I just think it could be written simpler... just trying to make sure I don't misunderstand things

Comment: You may be less confused by looking at the standard text that comes from.

Comment: @GoranFlegar We simply split the middle bullet into 3.

Comment: @T.C. yes, I figured it out after posting, I just didn't have any "useful" further comments to contribute :)

Comment: Ok, after thinking about it a little, maybe I have something to contribute: How I see it, the standard defines the 5 initialization categories mentioned above as separate entities. Thus, as far as cppreference is concerned, they are correct in quoting the standard literally. The only thing that can be improved there is to indicate that each of these categories has its own definition, and is not related to other categories. Whether there is some overlap between them is a question for the standard.